# Find file open with IDA PRO

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

How can I easily find which files are open/accessed by a program when i try to reveres engineer it with IDA pro and when this access takes place?
I do not mean the import files.

e.g. user configuration files. 
i may have the file name or not.

Thank
you

Comment: If you can run the program, you can use in Windows ProcMon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to check what files are accessed. For Linux you can use strace. For OSX you can use dtruss

Answer (score -1):

In IDA, you can follow all the references for functions related to opening files.
For example OpenFile ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile)), if the program run in Windows